# Cytoscape 3.10.0 only opens from terminal in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, cytoscape

I can successfully open the application from the ~/Cytoscape_v3.10.0/cytoscape.sh script, but the clicking the icon in the applications list does absolutely nothing, and likewise right-clicking a '.cys' file to open with cytoscape (which appears in the app list) does nothing as well.

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue. Fixed in 3.10.1, which will be release soon.

Comment: Absolutely correct.